Is there a way to tell the .NET compiler that a variable is not null?
If I have the following method
public int Add(int? a, int? b) {
    a ??= 0;
    b ??= 0;
    return a + b;
}

The last line will yield an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'"
I can fix this by either adding an explicit cast ((int)(a + b)) or by null-coalescing each operand ((a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0))..
My question is: is there some way to tell the compiler that since we already coalesced each variable to 0, they can be treated as ints instead of int?s?
TypeScript has an example of the functionality I'm asking about. In TS, the following code works because, by the time we get to the last line, the compiler knows that a and b are both number types, not number | undefined.
const add = (a?: number, b?: number): number => {
  // At this point, a and b are both number | undefined
  a ??= 0; // a is now number
  b ??= 0; // b is now number
  return a + b; // a + b returns number, not number | undefined
}


Yes: use .Value.

That's effectively the same as the other two alternatives I mentioned. I'm wondering if there is some way to simply say "return a + b;"

Can you provide an example closer to what you're actually trying to do? Having an Add method that allows null arguments makes no sense in the example context. In the above you could simply replace the int? with int a = 0 and not have to worry about null checks.

int? is its own type, i.e. Nullable<Int32> It's not a compiler feature like nullable reference types.

If a and b were reference types this would work but int is a value type and cannot be null. int? is syntactic sugar for Nullable<Int32> so you have to use Nullable<T>.Value to retrieve the underlying value of the variables.

return a! + b!;

another possibility is simply
return (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0);

You mentioned that last one already so why not use it?

Thanks for your answer! Null forgiving or null coalescing work well for simple cases like my example; however, for more complex methods, it would be easier/cleaner to tell the compiler "I already know this isn't null, I don't want to continue checking it again and again". Other languages such as TypeScript and Rust have features like this so I was wondering if .NET did, too.

If this answer is what you were looking for please mark it as accepted.

The error message is complaining about a type mismatch for the objects, not the value in the objects. That is, just because you've ensured both a and b actually have a value, it doesn't mean they aren't still int? values instead of int.
Therefore from a type safety standpoint you can't use those int? values directly to get an int result (you still have an int?). You need to either use the .Value property or some other work-around.
